# Django query with foreign key- output should be from two models

Tags: python, django

I am creating a querying website, which has two models, which connect with a foreign key. My goal is to have a searching page, where I given in a Person_ID as an input and get both Person and Report data (Report_ID, file_ID, Person_ID, name). Right now upon Person_ID entry it gives out Report data, but for some reasons, it does not give out the Person_ID itself and nothing from the Person table.
my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Person_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Person_ID

class Report(models.Model):
    Report_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    file_ID = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Report_ID
```

view.py:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        object_list= Report.objects.filter(
            Q(person__Person_ID__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

admin.py

```
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("Report_ID", "file_ID",)

admin.site.register(Report)
admin.site.register(Person)
```

Comment: The `Person` data can be accessed from the `Report`s, `report.person.id`. Is accessing them via the foreign key enough?

Comment: Yes, the Person data is accessible (because I query with Person_ID and I get the relevant Report), but somehow it doesn't appear in the query results. Even the Person_ID doesn't appear.

Comment: What "query results"? If you add `select_related('person')` to the queryset then the Person fields will be selected too

Comment: Okay, you were right. This was the solution. I didn't know select_related. Thanks a lot!